# Pyinstaller Exe, запущенный через другой exe, работает не с нужной директории

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, executable

В общем и целом, у меня есть exe, собранный через pyinstaller одним файлом. Данный питоновский exe файл запускается "лаунчером"(другой exe), который расположен отдельно от скрипта. Сам скрипт на питоне содержит в себе работу с файлами, которые лежат вместе с ним в директории. Но при запуске через лаунчер, скрипт думает, что он находится в директории самого лаунчера, а не там, где лежит. Мне нужно чтобы запущенный pyinstaller exe работал именно из той папки, где он находится при запуске из под лаунчера

Answer (score 0):

Немного муторно описана проблема, заранее прошу прощения если неправильно понял. Вам необходимо изменить текущий каталог для запущенного скрипта (каталог, в котором будет работать скрипт).

Например у меня есть /home/arise/py/test.py

test.py

```
import os
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Current Working Directory " , os.getcwd())
    my_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
    print("Script Location: ",my_path)

    print("change working dir....")
    os.chdir(my_path)
    
    print("New Working Directory " , os.getcwd())
```

и я его запускаю из /home/arise

скрипт изменяет рабочий каталог на тот, в котором собственно находится:

```
arise@arise-desktop:~$ python3 ./py/test.py
Current Working Directory  /home/arise
Script Location:  /home/arise/py
change working dir....
New Working Directory  /home/arise/py
```